# Moving from v4 to v5 broke my CleaveJS controlled TextField implementation, and I can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

Fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-bohr-x04cjf?file=/src/App.js

```
const CleaveField:FC<FormFieldProps> = (props) => {
const {onBlur = null, display, inputProps, InputProps, control, name, register, initialValue, errors, info} = props
  return (
    <Box errors={errors} info={info}>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        defaultValue={initialValue ? initialValue : ""}
                onBlur={onBlur}
        render={({ field }) => {
                    if (onBlur) {
                        field = {...field, onBlur}
                    }
                    return (
                        <TextField
                            {...field}
                            {...FORM_DEFAULTS}
                            error={errors && errors.length > 0}
                            label={display}
                            inputProps={inputProps}
                            InputProps={{
                                inputComponent: CleaveTextField
                            }}
                        />
                    )
                }}
      />
    </Box>
  )
}
export const CleaveTextField:FC = ({ inputRef, ...otherProps }) => (
  <Cleave {...otherProps} inputRef={(ref) => inputRef(ref)} />
)
```

Above is the code that was stable in v4. The problem is that the TextField improperly initializes the initialValue. It does not trigger the TextField value != zero mechanism, pictured below:
[image: Improper rendering of TextField]
There are some instructions for the migration that I attempted, but so far my attempts have been fruitless. https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#heading-textfield

```
//Change ref forwarding expectations on custom inputComponent. The component should forward the ref prop instead of the inputRef prop.

-function NumberFormatCustom(props) {
-  const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;
+const NumberFormatCustom = React.forwardRef(function NumberFormatCustom(
+  props,
+  ref,
+) {
  const { onChange, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <NumberFormat
      {...other}
-     getInputRef={inputRef}
+     getInputRef={ref}
```

I have reviewed the git issues and there is nothing outstanding, so either my use case is narrow and there is a bug or I am failing to implement the new API for v5. In either case I have spent way more time than I'd like to admit trying every combination of props to fix this, to no avail.
If I cannot find a solution, my workaround will be to enable the helperText field instead of label, which will break consistency for my form designs.

If anyone has insight here I would be hugely grateful! Thanks.

Current iteration: (Fails identically to the legacy code)

```
const CleaveField:FC<FormFieldProps> = (props) => {
  const {onBlur = null, setValue: setValueForm, display, inputProps, InputProps, control, name, register, initialValue = "", errors, info} = props
  const {
    field: { onChange, onBlur:onBlurField, name:formName, value, ref },
    fieldState: { invalid, isTouched, isDirty },
    formState: { touchedFields, dirtyFields }
  } = useController({
    name,
    control,
    defaultValue: initialValue,
  });
  return (
    <Box errors={errors} info={info}>
      <TextField 
        {...FORM_DEFAULTS}
        value={value}
        name={formName} 
        error={errors && errors.length > 0}
        label={display}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur || onBlurField}
        inputProps={{...inputProps}}
        InputProps={{
          inputComponent: CleaveTextField,
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
export const CleaveTextField = React.forwardRef(function CleaveTextField(
  props,
  ref,
) {
  return <Cleave {...props} ref={ref}/>
})
```

Comment: can you show the code that you HAVE, not the code that you HAD

Comment: @Bravo updated it to include the most recent attempt, though it is functionally failing the same way as the v4 legacy code.

Comment: huh? *it is functionally failing the same way as the v4 legacy code* - I thought you said the V4 code was stable - I wonder if it's something in `FORM_DEFAULTS` that is causing the issue

Comment: V4 code was stable *in v4*. But, since upgrading to v5 it has been failing.

Comment: that's what the question said, the comment confused me :p

Comment: I removed FORM_DEFAULTS and it fails. Just looks different

Comment: I didn't suggest removing it